# Why is 4.99 saved as 4.98?

Tags: rust

I might have found a glitch in the matrix. A client reported a bug: they set a product price of `4.99` through the backend and said it saved as 4.98.

I suspected that they've mistyped the value so I tested it myself and indeed the value came up as `4.98` **instead** of `4.99`. All other product prices seem unaffected. Bunch of 0.99s, 1.99s and 19.99s. I thought we might have introduced this bug recently, as this is the first and only time the client reported seeing such an issue.

To give you some more context, it's a React UI that uses apollo graphql to shove data to the backend which is Rust (actix). The backend then saves whatever needs saving in the database and the product price gets send to stripe through their API. The 4.98 is in stripe. The way the stripe API accepts prices is in unit amount, which is in cents, not dollars. So `4.99` should land in stripe as `499`. According to their dashboard our backend sent `498`. Wat?!

**few moments later**

I couldn't narrow down anything obviously wrong with the code. The graphql mutation sends it as float value `4.99`, it saves in our database as `FLOAT(4,2)` again as `4.99`, but the price ends up as `4.98` in stripe.

The way we prepare the value for the stripe API is:

```rust
let unit_amount = (product_price_row.price * 100f32) as i64;
```

Where `product_price_row` is the SeaORM row and `price` holds `4.99`.

In this case `unit_amount` ends up as `498`.

No other value seems to glitch like that.

I realize this is some quirky floating point error cluster f-ery, but it caught my attention. I wrote a small rust sandbox to illustrate what's going on. To test it out for yourself check this  [repository](https://github.com/iganev/yo_wats_up_with_4.99).

Basically it boils down to the following:

```rust
let i = 4.99; // any other .99 number works fine

println!("i = {}", i); // 4.99
println!("i.2 = {:.2}", i); // 4.99
println!("i.10 = {:.10}", i); // 4.9900000000

println!();

let f = format!("{:.10}", i).parse::<f32>().unwrap(); // lets introduce some errors
println!("f = {}", f); // 4.99
println!("f.2 = {:.2}", f); // 4.99
println!("f.10 = {:.10}", f); // 4.9899997711 <- here it goes

println!();

let d = f * 100f32;
println!("d = {}", d); // 498.99997 <- blyatiful
println!("d.2 = {:.2}", d); // 499.00
println!("d.10 = {:.10}", d); // 498.9999694824

println!();

let a = d as i64; // how the code used to work
println!("a = {}", a); // 498

let b = format!("{:.2}", d).parse::<f32>().unwrap() as i64; // workaround
println!("b = {}", b); // 499
```

In the above code, `a` represents the value reported by the client and `b` represents my workaround to fix it.

Replacing `i` with any .99 number doesn't behave the same way. To prove that `4.99` is an outlier I made another small binary (in the same repository). Run `cargo run --bin itr` to test it out for yourself. It starts from 0 until it explodes or you stop it (CTRL+C) and displays "defective" numbers that fail the `a == b` test.

The only number I get this result for is `4.99`.

Any suggestions how to work more properly with floats in Rust?

Comment: Look into what floating points are and what happens when you round them.  Since prices generally stop at two digits and tend to just get added, you should be better off storing as fixed point (LSB value of .01)

Comment: I have a generally good idea how floating point numbers work, I just found the 4.99 case more interesting than the usual struggle. Thanks to John for the detailed deep dive.

Comment: Side-note: Why are you using `f32` for the prices in fractional dollars, and `i64` for the prices in cents? If my brain isn't offline (it might be), `f32` will start losing precision for prices in the high five figure range, so prices close to $100K or more will drop information in the cents range, and now your books won't add up any time you sell a luxury car. Use `f64`, and the prices needed to cause that problem rise to unimaginably huge figures (barring Zimbabwean hyperinflation, we won't hit those for several lifetimes).

Comment: The Stripe SDK for rust requires that unit_amount is i64. Internally we deal with prices in f32 and FLOAT(4,2). The cast is just before sending to stripe. The app has pretty limited requirements for prices so we tried to keep it simple on our end.

Comment: @iganev: Okay, if the prices always fit `FLOAT(4,2)` (no price ever exceeds `99.99`), then `f32` is fine. I was not arguing against `i64` for the cents value, that's fine as is). I will say that, future-proofing-wise, assuming you'll never sell anything with a unit price above `99.99` is making work for your future self/some-future-maintainer that doesn't seem justified. That's on top of `FLOAT(m,d)` syntax [being deprecated in MySQL 8.0.17](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html). Use plain `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` (or `FLOAT(23)`/`FLOAT(53)` if you must).

Comment: `REAL(m,d)` is the only one not deprecated AFAICT, so you could use `REAL(4,2)`, but again, future-proofing says make that more like `REAL(10,2)` or the like.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Considering inflation, if you really want to future-proof, you'll use `TEXT`. /s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casting after performing floating point math, without first rounding, is *wrong*. When you do:

```
let unit_amount = (product_price_row.price * 100f32) as i64;
```

with `product_price_row.price` as `4.99f32`, `4.99f32 * 100f32` in `f32` math is clearly producing a value more like `498.99999999998` or the like (I can't be bothered to find the exact value), due to [floating point precision limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/364696), and casting just *drops* the data after the decimal, rather than rounding, leaving you with `498` rather than the expected `499`.

Instead do:

```
// Casting to f64 before doing math removes risk of data loss for higher prices
let unit_amount = (product_price_row.price as f64 * 100f64).round() as i64;
```

or (in cases where the decimal points might go beyond the second decimal place), using [`libmath`](https://docs.rs/libmath/latest/math/round/):

```
let unit_amount = math::round::half_to_even(product_price_row.price as f64 * 100f64) as i64;
```

which uses "Banker's rounding" to ensure round-offs of half values don't consistently go one way or the other, minimizing the risk of rounding bias in aggregate.

Either way, instead of that `.999999998` getting dropped, you'll round off correctly, *then* cast the now safe value.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I like your approach. Surely is more robust than my workaround. I still find it interesting why only 4.99 of all .99s falls into this trap...

Comment: @iganev: It's not something anyone who doesn't grok IEEE 754 binary floating point at a deep level can predict (beyond the simple rule that only decimal values evenly divisible by a power of 2 can be perfectly represented, everything else is imprecise). Which values have the problem varies between `f32` and `f64` math, and you'll only notice the problem when the multiplication happens to go under the "real" target; it's going *over* all the time, you just don't notice because you cast it away. I guarantee if you explore the price space more thoroughly, you'll find many instances of this issue.

Comment: I slightly misspoke in the comment: Only values with a decimal component *producible* by dividing an integer value by a power of 2 can be perfectly represented. Obviously values with a decimal component of any stripe aren't evenly divisible by anything.